# Spring Ehcache3 cause exception with key-type and value-type

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, types, ehcache-3

my issue is the same of this [Spring Ehcache3 cause exception with with key-type and value-type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45737109/22568819),
the only difference is that I don't have an .xml file, I have this CacheConfig instead:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        // creation of cache configuration
        CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfiguration = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                        String.class, String.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(1000).build()
                ).build();

        // fetching cacheManager
        CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

        // parsing ehcache configuration to something SpringBoot will understand
        javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<String, String> configuration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration);

        // creating as many caches as you want
        cacheManager.createCache("serviceHostName", configuration);

        // add shutdown hook to close cacheManager
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(cacheManager::close));

        // return Bean
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

But when I deploy project, I have this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheCacheConfiguration.class]: Cache [serviceHostName] specifies key/value types. Use getCache(String, Class, Class)....
    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache [serviceHostName] specifies key/value types. Use getCache(String, Class, Class)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager.getCache(Eh107CacheManager.java:271) ~[ehcache-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0 6973aca181d2b3e0010945a89933f3c99f4460c5]....
```

What is need to do, that I can use own key type and value types?

Comment: You should upgrade, as you are on v3.0.0 which [asserts](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/v3.0.0/107/src/main/java/org/ehcache/jsr107/Eh107CacheManager.java#L256C2-L275) that `getCache(String)` uses `Object.class` for the key/value type. The jsr107 spec was [changed](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/commit/403cb2b86813b18e1febdfa3143724df65b14ad1) in 1.1 to no longer require this check.

Comment: @BenManes Sorry, you know if it is possible to use "@Cacheable" on an interceptor method?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used either Spring or Ehcache for many years. ChatGPT seems to say that is non-standard scenario, so you either write your own caching abstraction or annotate the target method.