# Why Spring Boot causes Ehcache to throw ClassCastException when declaring Key or Value in configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ehcache-3

In a Spring Boot 3 application I implemented `Ehcache` for Hibernate 6. As [documentated here](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/getting-started.html#configuring-with-xml) and at tons of websites elsewhere too, I've set up a simple cache configuration for a simple class (no further realtionships, no whats'o'ever tricky somewhat):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xmlns:jsr107="http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3
                            http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core.xsd">

    <cache-template name="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">600</ttl>
        </expiry>

        <resources>
            <!-- Only the use of 'unit' is deprecated, not the property itself. -->
            <heap>1000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>

    <cache alias="email-status-cache" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.Integer</key-type>
        <value-type>com.example.tryout.EmailStatus</value-type>
    </cache>
</config>
```

The entity is annotated as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "email-status-cache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "email_status")
public class EmailStatus implements Serializable {

    //...
}
```

Now, doing it this way, the start up of the application fails with a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid key type, expected : java.lang.Integer but was : org.hibernate.cache.internal.BasicCacheKeyImplementation
```

Removing the `key-type` while the `value-type` remains throws another `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid value type, expected : com.example.tryout.EmailStatus but was : org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl
```

Only when I abstain from declaring any types within the configuration file the application is willing to run.

Since all documatations, which I've seen, declare theses properties, I'm not quite sure, whether I'm missing something or this is the correct way. Unfortunately, there is not a single documentation/example to find which is up to date, so this may be a thing only regarding the current tech stack - but I'm not that expert to declare this behavior normal.

Can anybody, who is familiar with Spring Boot 3, Hibernate 6 and Ehcache 3 explain what the proper configuration is and why?

Comment: You are trying to configure a second level caching system for Hibernate here. Since you are not caching manually the output of a cacheable method (ex: `@Cacheable(...)`) then those properties will produce an error.

Comment: You don't require to annotate with `@Cacheable()`, Hibernate explicitly says that this is redundant and you can omit this annotation. The cache works fine, it's just the Exception, which bothers me a bit. The exception is thrown no matter whether you annotate with `@Cacheable()` or not.

Comment: My bad I realized I was not clear enough when I said "caching manually". What I was trying to explain is, in a ehcache configuration file, setting `key-type` and `value-type` is only interesting if you use `@Cacheable` at a method level in your application (not at the class level) ex: `@Cacheable(value="emailStatus", key="#theKey") public EmailStatus getEmailStatus(final Integer theKey) {...}`

Comment: Ah well, that's what you've meant. Yes, I know that, and I also know that specifying no key and no value will default to Java Object. So in the end, as long as you don't give much about pseudo type safety it's all well. But nevertheless, I just wanna know why there are still no actual examples to find with a proper explanation of how and why things are done differently now. Or, if they are still done exactly like before, then it would be me not being able to get the config working - which would leave me with more questions than before as well...

Comment: Since Spring provide abstraction to ehcache I guess you should refer to their documentation first rather than the one from ehcache (but I was personally not able to find something in it). To answer your primary question here is an interesting answer from another similar SO question  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746163/11648839

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I know this comment, it's the only one to find with at least a try to give a little bit of information. But I'm somehow not convinced at all, because of two things: first, as mentioned above, there is not a single code example to find with an actual configuration from anyone who claims to be an expert, and second, although Hibernate and Ehcache are impemented in a Spring Boot application, the setting is done explicitly for Ehcache and the annotation used is from Hibernate. Thus this should be Hibernate/Ehache related and less a Spring Boot thing. But who am I to know...